# Why is Oracle Apex changing the value of company_id when I try to save IG using PL-SQL

Tags: plsql, oracle-apex

Using region source as the target type it updates/inserts without any issue.
However I need to give specific instructions and I'm trying to use custom PL-SQL for that.
It is changing one of the values and trying to insert that wrong value.

Without giving too much away I'm using the following structure:

```
begin
    case :APEX$ROW_STATUS
    when 'C' then
        insert into emp ( empno, ename, deptno, company_id )
        values ( :EMPNO, :ENAME, :DEPTNO, :company_id )
        returning rowid into :ROWID;
    when 'U' then
        update emp
           set ename  = :ENAME,
               deptno = :DEPTNO,
               company_id = :company_id
         where rowid  = :ROWID;
    when 'D' then
        delete emp
         where rowid = :ROWID;
    end case;
end;
```

I tried to debug and this is what I believe is the most relevant info:

```
APEX_DEBUG.ENABLE;
APEX_DEBUG.MESSAGE('Company_id: ' || :COMPANY_ID);
```

```
.........Session State: COMPANY_ID=>1
(...)
ignoring component value for COMPANY_ID - always use built-in value
(...)
Company_id: 1834779463308931
```

I also tried to create a new IG from scratch and I got the same problem. If I manually set the value in the pl-sql code it inserts/updates with no problems so I now that is the only problematic column.

I also don't have no other processes interfering with the value.

Can you guide me on what else I can try?

Comment: What are the settings of the column COMPANY_ID ? Any chance there is an application item with that name ? I'd suggest doing a application search for that string to check if it is set anywhere. You state that you tried to create a new IG from scratch... was that in the same app or in a new app ? If it works in another app then it is something in the original app that is causing this.

Comment: It was indeed some problem with the name of the column. I changed it to just COMPANY and it solved the problem. Thank you @KoenLostrie